# В google play не забанили приложения с чужим контентом

Tags: android, google-play

Все эти игры (фотка ниже) используют персонажей марвел в иконке, скриншотах, описании и в самой игре. Обычно гугл банит все приложения с чужим контентом - таких ситуаций было очень много.

Компании, которые сделали эти игры явно не имеют отношения к марвел и не имеют прав на их персонажей. Так в чем же дело ?. Мою игру вообще не пропустили в магазин (правла я использовал фотки персонажей прямо из фильмов).

Может дело в том что эти игры используют только арты персонажей, а не фотки из фильма. Если так, то можно ли брать арты с сайта www.deviantart.com ?, я вроде слышал что там всё можно использовать в коммерческих целях, это так или нет ?

В общем хочется узнать, почему эти игры не забанили и какие правила я должен соблюсти, чтобы не забанили меня.

[image: img1]

Comment: Такие игры не забанены, т.к. никто на них жаловался. Всё просто.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что лучше задать его саппорту Google.